# Select parents data and children count in SQL-Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a parent and a child table. It is a one-to-many relationship: a parent can have many children, a child can only have one parent.

I'm trying to create a query in SQLAlchemy that will give me all the parents' data, plus their children count.

So far I have this:

```
db.session.query(func.count(models.Child.id), models.Parent)\
  .select_from(models.Parent).join(models.Child).group_by(models.Parent.id)
```

This will produce SQL like this:

```
SELECT count(child.id) AS count_1, parent.id AS parent_id, parent.name AS parent_name
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
```

This gives me the desired results, **except if a parent has no children**. Then that parent is entirely omitted from the results, whereas the desired outcome is to have a row with its id, name, and a 0 count.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as an outer join.

In SQLAlchemy, use the `outerjoin` method instead of `join`, and you'll get the desired results.